# How to use if else to set var value in TextField

Tags: java, if-statement, actionlistener

can I ask how I can instantly equal my TextField named txtUserName into 'Aime' and also my txtPassword equal to 'Joy' so that it will show the message "User Name and Password Match!" ? Anyone? Please help me :(

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource()== btnClear){
    txtUserName.setText("");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == btnLogin){
        if (txtUserName.setText="Aime" && txtPassword.setText="JOy")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Name and Password Match!");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Name and Password Invalid!");
        }
```

Comment: can u describe your requirement?

Comment: does this code even compile??

Comment: Hello it is a Log-in Form , My professor ask me to insert an username in textfield1 and also a password in textfield2 and if they match on the required username and password the text "User Name and Password Match!" will print through JOptionPane and if it is not it would print  "User Name and Password Invalid!"

Comment: `txtUserName.setText="Aime"` is completely wrong here. First, setText is a function, not a field. Second, if you want to compare 2 two `String` (or 2 `Objects`), `equals` is always referred.

Answer (score 4):

These are the Small modifications needed.

```
if (txtUserName.getText().equals("Aime") && txtPassword.getText().equals("Joy")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Name and Password Match!");
}else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Name and Password Invalid!");
}
```

For your reference : [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java][1])

Comment: Hello Thank you it works but how about if it is not equal? what would I use?

Comment: Updated answer with  the else condition. No changes needed.

Answer (score 2):

you have two problems here:

```
txtUserName.setText="Aime" && txtPassword.setText="JOy"
```

am guessing you are trying to check the user input so you need to use the gettext method...

on the other hand you can not compare strings using ==, but furthermore you mistyped the == and are instead of comparing assigning, assignment that is invalid since you can not set the text of that view in that way...

try instead

```
txtUserName.getText().toString().equals("Aime") && ...
```

Comment: Yes , I think that's the problem

Comment: how about if in else I will put not equals , what codes I am going to insert? Thank you so much by the way.